# react render plain squares insted of images (matirial ui)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have this component supposed to display all the images from the event:

```
 function ViewEvent() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const { data, isPending, error } = useView(id);
  const photos = data?.event.photos;
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="view-event">
      <h1>{data && data.event.title}</h1>
      <input accept="image/*" id="icon-button-file" type="file" />
      <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
        <IconButton color="primary" component="span">
          <PhotoCamera />
        </IconButton>
      </label>
      {photos && (
        <ImageList sx={{ width: 500, height: 450 }} cols={3} rowHeight={164}>
          {photos.map((photo: IPhoto) => (
            <ImageListItem key={photo.img}>
              <img
                src={photo.img}
                srcSet={photo.img}
                alt={photo.key}
                loading="lazy"
              />
            </ImageListItem>
          ))}
        </ImageList>
      )}

      {isPending && <div>Loading</div>}
      {error && (
        <div className="error">
          <h2>{error.message}</h2>
          <Link to={"/login"}> go back to login</Link>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

All the images are stored in the file system and the path for them is stored in `photo.img` (photo.key is id). However I get this page instead:

[image: Blank Square screenshot]

basically blank square.

Edit the event data:

[image]

Comment: I would think that your path is incorrect. Try inspecting img element and opening it's source.

Comment: Please share a sample of the output of `console.log(data)` as well as checking the paths.

Comment: Do not look the image address would function as an image source.

Comment: Why the image path has double slash \\